# Finding a suitable set for equality of norms.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathcal{A}$. For each fixed $f\in L^{\infty}(X)$ consider the linear functional $$F(g)=\int_X fg\;d\mu,\quad g\in L^1(X).$$ It is easy prove that $F\in(L^1(X))^*$ and that $\lVert F \rVert \le \lVert f \rVert_\infty$. The opposite inequality is also easy to prove, but I can't find the following set: (given $\varepsilon>0$)

> By the fact that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite we can choose a set $A\in\mathcal{A}$ with $0<\mu(A)<\infty$ such that $$|f(x)|>\lVert f \rVert _\infty -\varepsilon\;\forall x\in A$$

**My solution.**

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be fixed and let $S=\left\{x\in X\; |\; f(x)\ne 0\right\}$. We define $$\Large A_{\varepsilon}=\left\{x\in S\; :\; \lvert f(x) \rvert > \lVert f \rVert_\infty-\varepsilon\right\}.$$

*Claim. $\mu(A_{\varepsilon})>0$*. Let $x\in X\setminus A_{\varepsilon}$ then we have that:

if $x\notin S$, then $\lvert f(x) \rvert=0 \le\lVert f \rVert_\infty - \varepsilon.$

if $x\in S$, then $\lvert f(x) \rvert \le\lVert f \rVert_\infty - \varepsilon.$ Then results $$\lvert f(x) \rvert \le \lVert f \rvert_\infty-\varepsilon\quad\forall x\in X\setminus A_{\varepsilon}.$$ Since $A_{\varepsilon}$ is a $\mu-$ null set we have that $\lVert f \rVert_\infty\le\lVert f \rVert_\infty-\varepsilon$ and this is a contradiction. Moreover, since $\mu(A_\varepsilon)>0$, necessarily $A_\varepsilon \ne\emptyset$.

Since $\mu$ is $\sigma-$ finite exists an increasing sequence $\{E_n\}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ such that $$X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n,\quad \mu(E_n)<\infty\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$ Therefore $$A_{\varepsilon}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(A_\varepsilon\cap E_n\right),$$ where $\{A_\varepsilon\cap E_n \}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ in an increasing sequence and $$0<\mu(A_\varepsilon)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_\varepsilon\cap E_n),$$ then exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mu(A_\varepsilon\cap E_{n_0})>0$, moreover $\mu(A_\varepsilon\cap E_{n_0})\le\mu(E_{n_0})<\infty$ and therefore we can take $$A:=A_{\varepsilon}\cap E_{n_0}.$$

Comment: How about $A=\{x\in X; |f(x)|>\|f\|_{\infty}-\varepsilon\}$

Comment: @Hamdiken That set can have infinite measure.

Comment: @Hamdiken Yes, but I don't understand the sigma finiteness where it is used, could you explain on me better? I thank you.

Comment: @NatMath In what book / source did you find this exercise ?

Comment: Since $\mu$ is $σ-$ finite, for any measurable set $E$ you can find a subset with finite positive measure.